# getState() return value for java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements

The **AbstractQueuedSynchronizer** class, a base class for the **java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition** interface,  has a function called `getState()`

> protected final int getState()
>
> Returns the current value of synchronization state. This operation has memory semantics of > a volatile read.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> current state value

This function returns the current state of the Condition which I assume to be something like waiting, timed out waiting, aborted, signaled in int form.   Does anyone know where I can find the integer definitions of the getState() function?

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of the "state" value is up to the subclass - from the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html):

> This class is designed to be a useful basis for most kinds of synchronizers that rely on a single atomic int value to represent state. Subclasses must define the protected methods that change this state, **and which define what that state means in terms of this object being acquired or released**.

(my bold)

Answer (score 0):

Found in `com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.Sync`

```
/* Valid states. */
static final int RUNNING = 0;
static final int COMPLETING = 1;
static final int COMPLETED = 2;
static final int CANCELLED = 4;
static final int INTERRUPTED = 8;
```

Though interfaces usually don't describe implementation details, so the values might be associated to different events in other implementations.

Comment: That's what the state values mean for _that specific subclass of AbstractQueuedSynchronizer_ - the abstract class itself (by design) doesn't assign any semantics to the state field.

Comment: sure, that's what I wanted to say, it's just one possible implementation. Your answer is correct, didn't update the page before posting ;)